# B-spline Representation Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, scipy, spline

Trying to implement scipy module **splprep ** and **splev **in Javascript. I have been looking for some online resource on the same. Converting the existing fortran legacy code is a big hassle. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried using b-spline npm package but without proper knot values it won't exactly perform the operation that I require.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For b-splines in general, you can take a look at the references in scipy.interpolate.BSpline documentation.

For what `splrep` is doing with the knot placement, I doubt there's anything better than original papers by Dierckx, maybe also his book. These are also referenced in the scipy.interpolate documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Since the scipy library uses the legacy Fortran code it is quite challenging to migrate it to Javascript. Any suggestions you have for the same?